# What do I enter for "Android Package URL" when trying to create an Android app in AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

I am still developing my application. I want to test it with adverts.
What do I enter for "Android Package URL" when trying to create an Android app in AdMob?
Because I have not published it on the market place, because I have not finished it yet
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your mouse over the small question mark next to the input field to get some help.

Quote:

> If you are linking to an Android App that is not in the Android Market, you may use http://

Comment: I am not sure if it means you should literally enter http:// or if you should enter an http URL. Anyway I just entered http:// without anything after that before I put my app live and it worked without problems.

Comment: I think this think all people might know. & still they are looking for that means they have doubt on that help.
Question is what `If you are linking to an Android App that is not in the Android Market` statement means?

Answer (score 1):

Its your app package name, you can find it in your manifest file on your project.

```
market://details?id=<yourpackehename>
```

heres a sample

```
market://details?id=<en.riskcalc.main>
```